# Javascript image crop possible without canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, crop

There are lots of scripts and plugins on the web for Javascript image crop/resize. [Some](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-crop/) using the HTML5 canvas to crop a certain area and storing the image back to the client via DataUrl. But without canvas I tested the [jrac](https://github.com/trepmag/jrac) jquery plugin, but it only provides the cropping coordinates (x, y, width, height) in the end. There is never called an actual cropping function on the image.

How do I actually use these cropping coordinates on the Javascript image object? Can I only use CSS to show the image like being cropped or can I actually crop data out of that image into a new image in Javascript?

It seems to me that all Image crop plugins only provide a handy UI to get crop coordinates but the actual crop/resize must be done server-side with the image being sent to a php script, is that correct?

My question is the same as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666601/crop-an-image-based-on-coordinates-without-using-a-canvas), that has not been answered yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for is a library to read image data to 2d array of pixels (or a 1d array of pixels in case of the canvas), crop the pixels, and write it back to compressed image data.

Sorry to say but that library is the canvas. You can, of course, use css to fake it but all the image data is still there, you're just choosing to only show part of it.

Comment: If you have any server leverage you could send the image and the cropping parameters to the server and have it send back the cropped image data.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand. So my assumption is correct and plugins like Jcrop, Jrac etc. only provide the UI for the cropping action but have no capability to do crop on image data without php on server side?

Comment: That's correct. Unless it does use the canvas. But it sounds like you're not able to use Canvas in this project?

Comment: I can use canvas in my project, but I just wanted to understand the constraints and concepts of image crop/resize.

Comment: Fair enough. I would attempt to use the Client (canvas) to do this kind of processing first. Not only is there less traffic on the network but also the canvas is hardware accelerated. With PHP you won't find any hardware accelerated methods to crop an image so the CPU (instead of the GPU) will need to do this calculation and it will be taxing on your server. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Everything is possible in javascript (well almost everything)

To crop an image you need to side step the DOM and built in image handling API's and decode the image yourself. A lot of extra work involved but there is some help out there. A quick search on github found decoders/encoders for both jpg and png formats [Image decoders](https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&o=desc&q=image%20decoder&ref=searchresults&s=stars&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93) (I am sure there are plenty more about) so with a little work you should be able to modify them to do some cropping.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible with createImageBitmap

Syntax:

```
createImageBitmap(image)
createImageBitmap(image, options)
createImageBitmap(image, sx, sy, sw, sh)
createImageBitmap(image, sx, sy, sw, sh, options)
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/createImageBitmap

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below one ,But its using Canvas for rendering,

As of now there is no good lib available without canvas becuase it is very difficult to capture the point you selected and to do processing the thousands and thousands of pixels without Graphics Card ,

Canvas only having the functionality to use Graphics Card

intel and firefox is doing some concepts regarding this to introduce parallel processing in javascript

https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/